# How to convert base64String to blob and send to controller via ajax in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, base64, blob

I am new to ajax, currently I am using ajax trying to send base64string from view to controller and get a JsonResult as following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("UploadSignature", "JobList")",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { photoByte: base64String, eventRecordID: "123456" },
  success: function (result) {
              if (result.success === true) {
                 alert("Signature uploaded !");
              }
  },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
         }
  });
```

And my controller method is as following:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadSignature(string photoByte, string eventRecordID)
    {
         byte[] photoAfterConvert = Convert.FromBase64String(photoByte);
         ...             
         //Upload photoAfterConvert to server
         ...
         return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

However, the code above sometimes not working especially when the base64String is too long. Once I call the ajax, it hang and never go inside the controller method. Approximately 1 minute later, it will trigger the error callback function and the message is shown as below which is meaningless.

> {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Therefore, I was thinking is there any alternative way that I can send large string data from view to controller via ajax? Is sending blob a good choice? If yes, how can I achieve it by sending blob? What is the datatype that I need to put in the controller parameter to accept blob?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Base62ToBlob (dataURI) {
    'use strict'
    var byteString,
        mimestring

    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') !== -1) {
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    } else {
        byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    }

    mimestring = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    var content = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        content[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(content)], { type: mimestring });
}
```

call action metthod from client side:

```
function FileUploadServer (blob) {   
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", blob,  "FileName.png");
    $http.post("URL", fd, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    })
        .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
          
          
        });
}
```

server side call receiver method:

```
 public ContentResult Upload()
  {
      var files = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
      return CustJson( null);
   }
```

Comment: Hi @jayang pareek, thanks for the given method. May I know what is the data type that I should set in the controller when pass the blob? Still use string?

Comment: unfortunately, the ajax call still hang and come out with error, is there any other alternatives?

Comment: what error can you share with me? and how to you call?

Comment: after 2min hanging there, it comes out this error {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}