# Upload file with parameters Angular 10 to .Net Core Web API using FormData

Tags: c#, angular, form-data

I am looking for a way to attach parameters form along with a file using FormData.

so I have a file input and a form with many parameters.

this is how I send my file:

```
 let formData=new FormData();
 formData.append("file",<File>this.file);
```

this is my form:

```
 this.fileForm = this.fb.group({
  headline: [],
  fileType: [],
  fileCategory: [],
  fileEssence: []
});
```

I tried to add the form value like this:

```
 formData.append("params",this.fileForm.value);
```

but I can't find it in the c# code:

```
var form= Request.Form;
```

only brings the file object.

Is there another way to do this?

***update:***

this is my upload function in angular:

```
  save(){
   let formData=new FormData();
   formData.append("file",<File>this.file);
   formData.append("parameters",this.fileForm.value);
   this.fileService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe((res)=>{
  console.log(res);
})
```

}

file service:

```
 uploadFile(fileUpload: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(ApiConsts.uploadFile, fileUpload).pipe(
        map((res: any) => res))
}
```

C# function:

```
   public IActionResult UploadFile([FromForm] FileUploadDTO parameters, [FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
    }
```

FileUploadDTO class:

```
public class FileUploadDTO
{
 
    public FileCategory fileCategory { get; set; }
    public FileEssence fileEssence { get; set; }
    public FileType fileType { get; set; }
    public string  headline { get; set; }

}
```

the parameters var is empty, not null but all values are null.

Comment: what kind of parameters the file have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67264397/how-to-convert-base64string-to-blob-and-send-to-controller-via-ajax-in-asp-net-m/67264520#67264520 check this Answers

Comment: @tmsbrndz - it's a form full of parameters , ints and strings, filles b the user.

Comment: Angular 10 to .Net Core Web API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `formData` you can append blob or string.
So you can append values to formData and send it to backend. At backend you can get post parameters via `FromForm` attribute.

Here is my example:

```
const formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('file', this.file);
formData.append('fileType', this.fileForm.get('fileType').value);
formData.append('fileCategory', this.fileForm.get('fileCategory').value);
```

Get `formData` on backend:

```
public void FormHandler([FromForm] string fileType, [FromForm] string fileCategory, [FromForm] IFormFile file){
// do the stuff
}
```

Comment: @tmsbrndz-  I tried public void FormHandler([FromForm] FileUploadDTO parameters, [FromForm] IFormFile file){
// do the stuff
}, the parameters return empty

Comment: @tmsbrndz- I updates my question, please check it out, thanks

Comment: From where ``file`` is coming?

Comment: the problem is not with the file bu with the parameters.

Comment: uploadFile(event) {
    this.file = event[0];
  }

Comment: as I said you can append string or blob to ``formData``. So you need to to append each parameter one by one. I'm updated my code with 2 parameters

Comment: thanks, but i have about ten parameters, is not there a better way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231919/discussion-between-tmsbrndz-and-chana).